# Is the 100 development devices limit per account or per provisioning profile?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store-connect

I know for sure there is a 100 devices limit for app developers. I believed it is per account which means any developer account can register up to 100 development devices per year. And if all consumed, bad luck. No way to delete old devices.

Now I hear some developers say it is per provisioning profile. So if I want to use TestFlightApp I can make a provisioning profile for 100 testers of a app for donut bakers, and then another provisioning profile for 100 different testers of an app for learning math? So essentially there is no limit?

What worries to me is if I use TestFlightApp too much and the limit is 100 per developer account I end up with no free slots and can't add my own new development devices for example when the next iphone arrives.

Worries right or wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The limit is per developer account. Following each renewal you will have the chance to remove devices (and there will be a notice to this effect on the top of this page on the provisioning portal), but devices removed after you've begun adding devices again will still count towards the limit.

And obviously, 100 devices is the practical limit per provisioning profile too, but only because you can only have 100 devices for every account. You can't have two apps with 200 different devices (100+100) since you can't even have 200 different devices.

Comment: Then this means we really cannot make real beta tests with different users many times right?

Comment: Nope. Like Alex says, if you are a company with a D-U-N-S number (Google it), you may be able to get an enterprise license. With it, you may deliver apps that are intended for "internal use" without a device restriction. Apple themselves provided iWork beta apps during the iOS 5 beta in this way. You may also be able to load up provisioning profiles with a lot more devices; I'm not sure how this works.

Comment: Is it true that it only makes sense to remove devices right (or some time) before you renew the one year dev program membership? Granted it is true that the device count is renewed only upon membership refresh?

Comment: I think it's only possible after renewal but before any new devices have been added.

Answer (score 3):

The 100 device limit is definitely per account and not per provisioning profile. AFAIK - the devices added expires after a year, so in a year you can either re-add them or leave the free slots for your new iHardware.

Answer (score 2):

Yes is 100 devices.

The solution is to enroll for [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) and here you can have an "unlimited" number of devices. It should be a limit but I don't know it.